# Linked List Recursive Value Sum

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to recursively determine the sum of the values in a linked list.

I am aware of one recursive solution that works:

```
def sum_list_rec1(head_node: Node):
   if head_node == None:
       return 0

   return head_node.value + sum_list_rec1(head_node.next)
```

However, I am trying to use the pattern where a variable is passed to the recursive function initially which will store the total sum.

Here is the code:

```
def sum_list_rec2(head_node: Node):
   val_sum = 0
   calc_sum_rec(head_node, val_sum)
   return val_sum

def calc_sum_rec(head_node: Node, val_sum: int):
   if head_node == None:
      return

   val_sum += head_node.value
   calc_sum_rec(head_node.next, val_sum)
```

If I try to print out the output of the sum_list_rec2() function with a linked list (e.g. (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4)), I get an output of 0.

Comment: The line `val_sum += head_node.value` only affects that parameter, not the value that was passed in by the caller. Your first snippet is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @quamrana I thought that may be the issue. Could you point me in the right direction to better understand the underlying cause? A solution to adding the values of a linked list can be done in a way similarly to method 2 (passing in an [], and appending each value to the list before passing it to another call to the recursive function). Couldn't the 2nd method above use the same pattern? Has it something to do with the underlying data type int and array in Python?

Comment: First this: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your second snippet work by returning the new value:

```py
def sum_list_rec2(head_node: Node):
   return calc_sum_rec(head_node, 0)

def calc_sum_rec(head_node: Node, val_sum: int):
   if head_node == None:
      return val_sum

   val_sum += head_node.value
   return calc_sum_rec(head_node.next, val_sum)
```

Actually the second function is better like this:

```
def calc_sum_rec(head_node: Node, val_sum: int):
   if head_node == None:
      return val_sum

   return calc_sum_rec(head_node.next, val_sum + head_node.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers in Python are immutable, so every time you do `val_sum += head_node.value` you are basically creating a new integer, and the code is equivalent to `val_sum = val_sum + hash_node.values`.

A simple way to circumvent this problem is to wrap the integer inside an object:

```
class IntWrap:
    def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
        self.value = initial_value

def sum_list_rec2(head_node: Node):
   val_sum = IntWrap()
   calc_sum_rec(head_node, val_sum)
   return val_sum.value

def calc_sum_rec(head_node: Node, val_sum: IntWrap):
   if head_node == None:
      return

   val_sum.value += head_node.value
   calc_sum_rec(head_node.next, val_sum)
```

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. If it try to debug by printing out the val_sum within the recursive call, it prints out the correct sum of the values, showing that the val_sum value is preserved in the recursive function itself.

Comment: No, @dingo: this is entirely correct. But it doesn't stop `val_sum` being the correct value at the most recursive call.

Comment: @Luckk can you update your question with an example of using your class with the functions?

Comment: @Luckk - does using the IntWrap class work because we are no longer referencing an immutable type, but rather the value of an object?

Comment: @dingo yes, it works because the class IntWrap is mutable and you can change its properties without creating a new instance.